# Limiting revealing of sprite sheet as text box background

Tags: html, css, background, sprite-sheet

## What I have

I have two text boxes, each with a background image that changes on focus. All background images are derived from the one sprite sheet.

## What I need

I need the limit how much of the sprite sheet is revealed because the text box is larger than the amount of the background I wish to reveal.

## Important

Editing the markup is not an option. I require a CSS-based solution.

## My code

```css
#foo,
#bar {
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-image: url("http://s30.postimg.org/5huu7u8ip/test.png");
  padding: 0 1em;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 3em;
}
#foo {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#bar {
  background-position: 0px -50px;
}
#foo:focus {
  background-position: -50px 0px;
}
#bar:focus {
  background-position: -50px -50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click into and out of each box to toggle default and focus states:</p>
<p>
  <label for="foo">
    <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" id="foo" placeholder="foo" name="foo">
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="bar">
    <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" id="bar" placeholder="bar" name="bar">
  </label>
</p>
```

Using the above live example, there should never be a case where more than one icon showing. On focus is fine, the problem occurs on the default state of the text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some Javascript to `toggleClass` on the label when the input is on focused and unfocused. Note, I wrapped the p tags into a form and use `nth-*` selector to target the labels.

**[Jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6t1sw9hd/)**

```js
$('input').bind('focus blur', function () {
   $(this).parent('label').toggleClass('focus');
});
```

```css
label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-image: url("http://s30.postimg.org/5huu7u8ip/test.png");
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form p:nth-child(1) label:before {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
form p:nth-child(2) label:before {
  background-position: 0px -50px;
}
form p:nth-child(1) label.focus:before {
  background-position: -50px 0px;
}
form p:nth-child(2) label.focus:before {
  background-position: -50px -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click into and out of each box to toggle default and focus states:</p>
<form>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" id="foo" placeholder="foo">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" id="bar" placeholder="bar">
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
```

If yo can move the label after the input tag, then you can use CSS sibling selector `~` or `+` to do it. No Javascript is needed, see the demo below.

**[Jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dghcha4z/)**

```css
label {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-image: url("http://s30.postimg.org/5huu7u8ip/test.png");
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#foo + label {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#bar + label {
  background-position: 0px -50px;
}
#foo:focus + label {
  background-position: -50px 0px;
}
#bar:focus + label {
  background-position: -50px -50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click into and out of each box to toggle default and focus states:</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" id="foo" placeholder="foo">
  <label></label>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" id="bar" placeholder="bar">
  <label></label>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Pangloss but I may not have been sufficiently clear in specifying that desired effect is that the icons visually _appear_ to be WITHIN the text boxes (see the code sample in my question). Example: http://userloser.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/metro-form.jpg Thank you for taking the time to assist me.

Comment: I go that, it will just a matter of positioning, see this - https://jsfiddle.net/dghcha4z/1/

Comment: That's great. Delighted I can now use a sprite sheet instead of using CSS preloading (too many HTTP requests) and JavaScript (support not always guaranteed). Thanks for your patience and time.